# Chrome: What script is setting element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm working on a wordpress site that has a bunch of plugins...my suspicions point to some script within the theme, but I have a particular element that has it's height set to a fixed pixel size.  This is fine except for when trying to add dynamic content.  If I set the height to auto, it gets set back to a specified height.

So it seems to me that some javascript is setting the height of this element (maybe with a mutation event).  Is there a way in Chrome's web developer tools to see what script is setting the height (or any css) of an element?

I doesn't seem that breakpoints really help me here as the elements tab doesn't seem to update as I step through.

Any thoughts on debugging this one?

Answer (score 0):

If it's done with javascript, it either applies an inline css or a class. so you could find that with chromes developer tool (press F12).

Comment: Or Ctrl + Shift + J, I like this better cause I don't have to move my hand all the way across the keyboard :P

Comment: Right, it applies an inline css styles.  I can see the style...I just don't know what script is actually applying it.  That's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never did find what was setting the height of the div, but using a $(window).load and then setting the height to 'auto' fixed the problem.